# Can a .bat script write a a java file and compile it?

Tags: testing, scripting, batch-file

In [this README](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dp4j/files/README.txt/download) I give instructions for a quick CL for testing the released tool. I think it would be much better if I provided a .bat and unix script which executed the commands in one click/command. At the same time, unlike a compiled program, it's transparent and users can open the script with the editor and inspect the commands executed.

Can I in a bat save a file?
This is what I'd like it to execute.

```
$ vim Test.java (windows: notepad Test.java) 

class T { 
private static void p(int i, Double d, String... s){} 
} 

public class Test{ 

@com.dp4j.InjectReflection public void t() { 
T.p(1,new Double(2),"hello", "reflection"); 
} 
} 

$ ls Test.class T.class (windows: dir Test.class T.class) 
ls: Test.class: No such file or directory ls: T.class: No such file or directory

$ javac -cp dp4j-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar Test.java 
$ ls Test.class T.class (windows: dir Test.class T.class) 
ls Test.class T.class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a unix exectable script that does what I want. I don't know if it works with cygwin on windows:

```
#!/bin/sh

v=1.1
test_file="Test10.java"
jar_file="dp4j-$v-jar-with-dependencies.jar"

cmd="curl -O --fail -L http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/dp4j/$v/$jar_file"
echo $cmd
$cmd
echo

# Start
cat > $test_file << __EOF__
class T10 {
    private static void p(int i, Double d, String... s){}
}
public class Test10{
    @com.dp4j.InjectReflection
    public void t() {
  T10.p(1,new Double(2),"hello", "reflection");
    }
}
__EOF__
cmd="cat $test_file"
echo $cmd
$cmd

echo
cmd="javac -Averbose=true -cp $jar_file $test_file"
echo $cmd
$cmd
echo
echo "TEST PASSED: $test_file was compiled with Reflection Injected." 
echo "When JUnit/TestNG.jar is in the classpath you may use @Test in lieu of @InjectReflection."
echo "Javadoc, sources, and other artifacts maybe downloaded from http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/com/dp4j/dp4j/"$v"/"
```

Here's one line command to download it and execute it:

```
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/dp4j/files/1.2/TESTDRIVE ;  chmod +x TESTDRIVE ; ./TESTDRIVE
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

You can put each line in an `echo` command piped to the file:

```
echo class T { > MyFile.java
echo     private static void p(int i, Double d, String... s){} >> MyFile.java
echo }    >> MyFile.java
echo ...  >> MyFile.java
```

`>` creates a file; `>>` appends to it.

You can then compile it normally.

Comment: You can even put multiple `echo`es into a block surrounded by parentheses and use only a single redirection.

Answer (score 1):

Um, perhaps this?

```
// 2>NUL&GOTO :START
//Just ignore the above line, it's for the batch script.

class T { 
private static void p(int i, Double d, String... s){} 
} 

public class Test{ 

@com.dp4j.InjectReflection public void t() { 
T.p(1,new Double(2),"hello", "reflection"); 
} 
}

/*We start the batch script here.
:START
@CLS&ECHO OFF
START NOTEPAD %0
IF EXIST Test.class GOTO :EXISTS
IF EXIST T.class GOTO :EXISTS
JAVAC -cp dp4j-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar %0
GOTO :END
:EXISTS
ECHO There is a preexisting class file. Aborting.
:END
REM We end the batch script here.*/
```

By the way, here the batch script and java source are the same file.

Comment: I didn't manage to execute this. COPY CON dp4j-1.0-CLTEST.BAT ... and then executing it the javac will understandibly report that is an invalid option. Renaming it Test.java will have executing this wierdly named bat open in notepad but no compilation occurs